# Creating custom registration and login link in wordpress

Tags: user-registration

I am working on a WordPress website and using the following code for registration and login. This code contains a default register and login link. But I want to change default register/login box with example.com/my-account link.

```
<?php
$c_user = wp_get_current_user();
if( !is_user_logged_in( $c_user->ID ) ) :
wp_register('', '/');
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( 'Login', 'textdomain' ) . '">';
echo _e( 'Login', 'textdomain' );
echo '</a>';

else :
    echo 'Hello <a href="your_url">' . $c_user->display_name . '</a>, ';
    echo ' <a href="' . esc_url( wp_logout_url( home_url() ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( 'Logout', 'textdomain' ) . '">';
echo _e( 'Logout', 'textdomain' );
echo '</a>';

endif;
?>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the default example.com/wp-login.php to redirect to your own line example.com/my-account. Use .htaccess file (if you are using apache for http) and rewrite the URL from one to the other.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom yes, I want to use custom registration. I don't want to redirect the link to the custom link. I just want to add a custom link in registration and login link in the code.

Comment: are you unable to use a custom html widget. The risk of adding a custom link is that anyone from the outside can still call /wp-login.php or /wp-admin and get the old login / registration method. If you want to add it to code you might be able to create a function in functions.php. I'm out of my depth with that stuff :(

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom I added code in header.php. Whenever a user click on register button, they redirect to https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=register. I want to place example.com/my-account link instead of that link and the same on login button.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

```
<?php
   $c_user = wp_get_current_user();
   if( !is_user_logged_in( $c_user->ID ) ) :
   echo '<a href="' . esc_url( site_url("my-account") ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( 'register', 'textdomain' ) . '">';
 echo _e( 'register', 'textdomain' );
        echo '</a>';
   echo '<a href="' . esc_url( site_url("my-account") ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( 'Login', 'textdomain' ) . '">';
   echo _e( 'Login', 'textdomain' );
   echo '</a>';

   else :
       echo '<a href="' . esc_url( site_url("my-account") ) . '">';
   echo _e(  $c_user->display_name );
   echo '</a>';

       echo ' <a class="omlogin" href="' . esc_url( wp_logout_url( home_url() ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( 'Logout', 'textdomain' ) . '">';
   echo _e( 'Logout', 'textdomain' );
   echo '</a>';

   endif;
 ?>
```